# How can I get more than one property from an object list to an array?

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a LINQ statemant to transfer a List of a class like

```
private class ToSelectMany
{
  public string SelectMe1 { get; set; }
  public string SelectMe2 { get; set; }
  public string IgnoreMeString { get; set; }
  public bool IgnoreMeBool { get; set; }
}
```

to an array like

```
[0] "list element 1 - SelectMe1"
[1] "list element 1 - SelectMe2"
[2] "list element 2 - SelectMe1"
[3] "list element 2 - SelectMe2"
[4] "list element 3 - SelectMe1"
[5] "list element 3 - SelectMe2"
...
```

I tried

```
List<ToSelectMany> elements = GetElements();
string[] elementArray = elements.SelectMany(a => a.ToSelect1, b => b.ToSelect2);
```

and some similar things, but it won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to build an array of the *two strings* foreach element and then use `SelectMany` to concatinate them:

```
string[] elementArray = elements.Select(
     (a, i) => new string[] { 
                 "list elment " + (i + 1) + " - " + a.SelectMe1, 
                 "list elment " + (i + 1) + " - " + a.SelectMe2
     }).SelectMany(x => x).ToArray();
```

or for a better looking c# 6 version:

```
string[] elementArray = elements.Select(
     (a, i) => new string[] { 
                 $"list elment {i+1} - {a.SelectMe1}", 
                 $"list elment {i+1} - {a.SelectMe2}"
     }).SelectMany(x => x).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var i = 0;
var list = new List<string>();
elements.ForEach(p=>{
    i++;
    list.Add("list element " + i + " - " + p.SelectMe1);
    list.Add(("list element " + i + " - " + p.SelectMe2);
});
```